# ValueError truth value ambiguous when removing value from list which are values of a dictionary

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

I tested this piece of code:

```
dic = {1:[[[1],2],[[2],3],[[3],4]],2:[[[5],6],[[7],8]],3:[[[9],10],[[11],12]]}
klst = list(dic.keys())
# print(klst)
print(dic[1])
for item in dic[klst[0]]:
    if item == [[2],3]:
        dic[klst[0]].remove(item)
        print(item)
        break

print(dic)
```

I get the following output:

```
[[[1], 2], [[2], 3], [[3], 4]]
[[2], 3]
{1: [[[1], 2], [[3], 4]], 2: [[[5], 6], [[7], 8]], 3: [[[9], 10], [[11], 12]]}
```

So, the remove() perfectly removes the list from the value list of the dictionary.

I have implemented a similar structure where the *keys* are heuristic values and *values* are list of list. The inner list consists of an numpy array and a string. For example:

```
[array([[10,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  0,  9, 11]]), 'left']
```

Now I am trying to remove such list from the dictionary and getting

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The code worked for first two times removing such list from the dictionary

```
for move in index_move_priority:
            for item in open_nodes[keylist[0]]: # item in list of states
                if move == item[1]:
                    print("KLYST",keylist[0])
                    print("////////////////",open_nodes[keylist[0]])
                    print("ITEM->",item)
                    print(type(open_nodes[keylist[0]]))
                    print(type(item))
                    open_nodes[keylist[0]].remove(item)
                    find_neighbor_node = item
                    temp = True
                    break
            if temp == True:
                break
```

Here *open_nodes* is my dictionary. The line

```
open_nodes[keylist[0]].remove(item)
```

is causing the ValueError. I have printed the contents of *keylist[0]* as well as *open_nodes[keylist[0]]* as follows before the error.

```
KLYST 8
//////////////// [[array([[10,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  0,  9, 11]]), 'left'], [array([[10,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  0,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9,  5, 11]]), 'up-left'], [array([[10,  1,  0,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  2,  7],
       [ 8,  9,  6, 11]]), 'up'], [array([[10,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  0,  5,  7],
       [ 8,  9,  6, 11]]), 'left'], [array([[10,  0,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  1,  7],
       [ 8,  9,  6, 11]]), 'up-left']]
ITEM-> [array([[10,  1,  0,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  2,  7],
       [ 8,  9,  6, 11]]), 'up']
```

I don't understand why I am getting the ambiguous value error.
UPDATE: Find the code here https://github.com/idk-kid/test/blob/master/test.ipynb

Comment: It would be much better to reduce your question, simply put your code, your result or error and the result you are looking for, most users helping here will be able to trace what went wrong in between the code and output and also provide a new route

Comment: list `remove` performs equality tests.  Boolean tests on arrays produce boolean arrays, one value per element of the array.  That's where the ambiguity error arises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`remove` uses an equality test.  Such a test on arrays is different from lists.

list remove:

```
In [86]: alist = [[1,2],[3,4]]
In [87]: alist.remove([1,2])
In [88]: alist
Out[88]: [[3, 4]]
```

array remove - your error

```
In [89]: alist = [np.array([1,2]),np.array([3,4])]
In [90]: alist.remove(np.array([1,2]))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-90-367c77859b46> in <module>()
----> 1 alist.remove(np.array([1,2]))

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

`remove` works if I reference the array by location.  The compare first tests ids:

```
In [91]: alist.remove(alist[0])
In [92]: alist
Out[92]: [array([3, 4])]
```

But if the ids don't match then it goes on to test values.  But boolean tests on arrays produce boolean arrays:

```
In [93]: alist[0]==np.array([3,4])
Out[93]: array([ True,  True])
```

Using a multi-element array in a context that expects a scalar (such an `if` clause) produces this abiguity error.

List comparisons can be made by value, returning a scalar:

```
In [94]: Out[88][0]==[3,4]
Out[94]: True
```

Lists and arrays are similar in many ways, but usually aren't dropin replacements for each other.

### edit

The same thing applies when the arrays are nested inside lists.  Using your last prints:

```
In [104]: alist.remove(item)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-104-f439b16b219c> in <module>()
----> 1 alist.remove(item)

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
In [105]: alist[0]
Out[105]: 
[array([[10,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  0,  9, 11]]), 'left']
In [106]: item
Out[106]: 
[array([[10,  1,  0,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  2,  7],
        [ 8,  9,  6, 11]]), 'up']
In [107]: alist[0]==item
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-d1fe30e1a331> in <module>()
----> 1 alist[0]==item

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
In [108]: alist.remove(alist[0])
In [109]: alist
Out[109]: 
[[array([[10,  1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  0,  6,  7],
         [ 8,  9,  5, 11]]), 'up-left'], [array([[10,  1,  0,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  2,  7],
         [ 8,  9,  6, 11]]), 'up'], [array([[10,  1,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  0,  5,  7],
         [ 8,  9,  6, 11]]), 'left'], [array([[10,  0,  2,  3],
         [ 4,  5,  1,  7],
         [ 8,  9,  6, 11]]), 'up-left']]
```

If list id's match it can remove.  But if they don't it resorts to comparing lists element by element.  But when one of those elements is an array, it hits the ambiguity problem.

Comment: In my code, the 2nd for loop iterates over the dictionary list reference open_nodes[keylist[0]] and so item actually refers to each element in that list. So, I shouldnt be getting this error. My code is inside another loop and this works fine for the first two iteration of the outer loop which is even more odd. I posted the whole code above.

Comment: The error is frequent on SO, and always has to do with some sort of boolean test involving an array.  The list and `item` at the error contain arrays.

Comment: I added a test case using your last list and item prints.

Comment: I got it. It was running for the first two iterations because item was the first element in the list. The third time it is not in first position. Therefore it causes the ambiguous error.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I have seen this once before in a SO,  Because of the id test a match can work on the first item, but  raise this error later.

Comment: One last question, it looks like you learn these things only by experiencing. I am sure I will encounter more errors like these in future. So, any suggestions where I can look into or how to search for such stuff when I get stuck?